# How to split break line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a question about my javascript.

i have something retrieved from my DB like this:

```
lots of texts in line 1 
lots of texts in line 2
lots of texts in line 3 
lots of texts in line 4
```

I want to create an array and create elements based on the breakline.

I have something like

```
var contents = obj.string //obj.string contains the contents above.
contents = contents.split(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g)
```

It created more than 4 elements because some elements are just a '`breakline`'.

Can anyone help me to get just 4 elements? Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: anyway you can loop through the elements and remove the empty elements (after trimming), then you should have only 4 elements remaining.

Comment: @bjb568 Not sure how this is a duplicate of your linked question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit in your question are two assumptions.  First, I assume that the line breaks may be indicated by either `'\r\n'`, `'\n'` or `'\r'`.  Second, you want to ignore empty lines in your result.

I think you can acheive both by first converting all the line breaks into a single form, then splitting while ignoring empty lines, like this:

```
contents.replace(/(\r\n)|\r|\n/g, '\n').split(/\n+/g)
```

The replace command should convert all the different line breaks to `'\n'`, while the split will split the line wherever it sees 1 or more consecutive `'\n'`s.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an elegant solution but you can sanitise the strings by replacing any `\r` with `\n` and then trim off the last `\n` (which will give you an empty array that you do not need).

See example:

```
var a = "a\nb\rc\n\n\n\n",
    b = a.replace(/\r/g,"\n").replace(/[\n]+/g,"\n").replace(/\n$/,"").split("\n");
```

output of `var a`:

```
"a
 bc



 "
```

output of `var b`:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

The process of cleaning up is as follows:

1. Take the string and replace all `\r` with `\n`, this will leave you with multiple `\n` in certain places
2. Clean multiple instances of `\n` to singulars
3. Remove any trailing `\n` to avoid an empty array element at the end
4. Split to array on the `\n`